# PHP, PDO and SQLSRV executes multiple times on one INSERT statement

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I've been using PDO and PHP for a while with MySQL and Apache servers. I've recently been tasked with converting a legacy web application for a business to a new setup. The old setup is a standard Linux web stack (Apache/PHP/MySQL/Filezilla) and the new setup will be a Windows server 2003 with IIS/PHP(fast cgi install)/ SQL Server 2003/No FTP.

I have nearly everything working except for a conversion of a MySQL statement to update a table with file access information. Using PDO with SQLSRV driver and executing an insert statement inside a 'file download' PHP script, inserts multiple records into the SQL table.

The download.php DOES issues multiple queries to the SQL server. Once to check for the file existence and variables in one table, and THEN updates another table with the access information.

> SEE BELOW FOR download.php CODE

Debugging shows the print/echo of $count as 1. Checking the SQL server records however, always shows MORE than one inserted. Sometimes it is just one extra row for a total of two, but other times it is as high as four EXTRA statements being inserted. $count remains shown as 1, in every case.

This particular PHP script verifies information against the SQL database prior to calling this insert statement. First, the verification of authentication for the file access(succeeds), verifies the file existence(succeeds), then updates the access table with information for the download (ERROR) and finally serves the PDF to the user (succeeds).

When I issue the INSERT statement manually into Query Analyzer, it succeeds and works as expected; it inserts one row every time. The error seems to be with SQLSRV or PDO implementation of the execute().

I have searched on stackoverflow, serverfault and the almighty Google for information regarding this. The only types of results returned where users needing to execute multiple queries/inserts in one statement/execute. Where's my issue is the opposite; I wish to only execute ONE insert statement however, more than one is always executed.

Question is: Why is this happening and how can I prevent the multiple insert from happening?

**UPDATE PER REQUEST**

The code that accesses this file is one singular link from another web page. The page lists current files the user is allowed to access and presents links to the download.php script for the verification, update and actual serving of the PDF.

View page has a list of links (printed in a for loop) arranged like :

```
<a href='download.php?f={$item['name']}&t={$type}' target='_blank'>{$item['name']}</a>
```

When the user clicks on that link, the script below is what runs in addition to the other code above for download.php. It successfully serves the PDF file. The content is being sent by download.php as a PHP header/inline PDF:

> SEE BELOW FOR CODE

Looking at the server logs shows **two** GET request to the download.php file:

```
2012-02-14 17:44:37 W3SVC1785071458 172.17.31.254 GET /download.php f=06304844-1A.pdf&t=av 4090 - 172.17.31.112 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/535.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/16.0.912.77+Safari/535.7 200 0 0
2012-02-14 17:44:37 W3SVC1785071458 172.17.31.254 GET /download.php f=06304844-1A.pdf&t=av 4090 - 172.17.31.112 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/535.7+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/16.0.912.77+Safari/535.7 200 0 0
```

I have tested in Firefox, Opera, and IE (6-9b) and the results are the same.

**UPDATE TWO**

Putting the entire download.php file here:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("cgi-bin/auth.php");

// Don't timeout when downloading large files
@ignore_user_abort();  
@set_time_limit(0);  

//error_reporting(E_ALL); 
//ini_set('display_errors',1);

function getfile() {
    require('cgi-bin/connect_db_pdf.php');
    //Verify information 
    if (!isset($_GET) || !isset($_GET['f']) || !isset($_GET['t'])) {
        echo "Nothing to do!";
        exit(0);

    }

    //Update variables
    $vuname = strtolower(trim($_SESSION['uname']));
    $file = trim($_GET['f']); //Filename we're looking for
    $type = trim($_GET['t']);//Filetype

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]{1,60}$/', $file) || !preg_match('/^av|ds|cr|dp$/', $type)) {
        echo "Non conforming values";
        exit(0);
    }

    try {

        $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM pdf_info WHERE PDF_name=:file AND PDF_type=:type";

        $statm = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
        $statm->execute(array(':file'=>$file,':type'=>$type));
        $result = $statm->fetch();
        $count = $statm->rowCount();
        $sQuery = null;
        $statm = null;

        if ($count == 1 ){ //File was found in the database so let them download it. Update the time as well

            $sQuery = "INSERT INTO access (PDF_name,PDF_type, PDF_time, PDF_access) VALUES (:file, :type, GetDate(), :vuname)";

            $statm = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
            $statm->execute(array( ':vuname'=>$vuname, ':file'=>$file, ':type'=>$type));
            $count = $statm->rowCount();
            $sQuery = null;
            $statm = null;

            $sQuery = "UPDATE pdf_info SET last_view=GetDate(),viewed_uname=:vuname WHERE PDF_name=:file AND PDF_type=:type";

            $statm = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
            $statm->execute(array( ':vuname'=>$vuname, ':file'=>$file, ':type'=>$type));
            $sQuery = null;
            $statm = null;

            //$result is from FIRST SELECT query outside this 'if' scope.
            $file_loc = $result['floc'];
            $file_name = $result['filename'];

            $fileh = fopen($file_loc,'rb');//Send content to browser as inline PDF
            header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
            header("Pragma: no-cache");  
            header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");  
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_loc));  
            header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
            header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename={$file_name}");  

            while (!feof($fileh)) { 
                echo(@fgets($fileh, 8192)); 
            } 

            fclose ($fileh); 
            exit(0);

            } else { //We did not find a file in the database. Redirect the user to the view page.
                header("Location: view.php");
            }

            }   catch(PDOException $err) {//PDO SQL error. 
            //echo $err;
            header('Location: error.php');
            exit(0);
         }
}

getfile();

?>
```

Comment: Please post more code. If you're getting multiple inserts, it is likely your script is being called multiple times, either because of faulty logic (e.g. when post has not been submitted yet), or because of faulty rewrite rules.

Comment: Watch your server's access log while this script runs to see if you're actually hitting it a couple of times.

Comment: What happens if you just do a simple test file that has only the code related to the INSERT?

Comment: @Michael I checked the server logs after restarting IIS. The script is in fact calling download.php twice. If the `$_GET` variables are not set or not expected values, the script exits. Then the logic goes onto the retrieving of file information and the download. Why would this cause the download script or my function to be executed more than once?

Comment: @PenguinCoder Please post the code that occurs before the insert code, the part which examines `$_GET` and exits.

Comment: @Farray: With a test file and hardcoded variables, the insert statement only executes ONCE as expected. Based on this, would the likely cause of my error be the multiple PDO prepare/execute statements in my download.php? How could I execute two separate statements using PDO without crossing the actual prepares?

Comment: @Michael: Added the complete file. To add, the `exit(0);` works as expected. When the INSERT is executed (twice/download.php being called twice on one click/call) the SQL server shows timestamps a few milliseconds apart. When the script exits (no `$_GET` or improper values) no INSERT is executed. (Expected behavior for that exit)

Comment: I'm not sure if this the source of your problems, but as far as I remember, SQLSRV (at least as of v2.0) does not allow/like named parameters in queries, i.e. you should just use `?` instead of `:file`.

Comment: `if (!isset($_GET) || !isset($_GET['f']) || !isset($_GET['t'])) {` is more simply written as `if (!isset($_GET['f'], $_GET['t'])) {`.  This condition `if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]{1,60}$/', $file) || !preg_match('/^av|ds|cr|dp$/', $type)) {` is better written as `if (!preg_match('/^\w.-]{1,60}$/', $file) || !in_array($type, ['av', 'ds', 'cr', 'dp'])) {`

Answer (score 1):

You comment that the download script is being called twice and should exit if the correct value is not found.  This may not be the case because you misuse PDOStatement's `rowCount()` to test for found files.  This method is intended to return the number of affected rows for DELETE, UPDATE, or INSERT statements, but **not SELECT**.

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. **However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases** and should not be relied on for portable applications.
>    http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

They continue on with:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned.

If you call the download.php script twice -- 1 time with incorrect file values (that happen to pass your regex test) and 1 time with correct values, it is quite possible you are inserting twice even though you are only downloading once.

Comment: I changed the `$result` to `$result = $statm->fetchAll();` and `$count` to `$count = count($result);` and gave each named bound parameter a unique name. With this, the INSERT for access table only occurs once. However, the UPDATE for pdf_info never occurs and the browser hangs and never delivers the PDF file. More than likely an error in some other logic and not related to this question.

Comment: The changes I made that gave the expected results where with a commented out `while` loop for PDF download. That way I could print the errors if any occurred. Removing THAT commenting around the `while` loop, the INSERT occurs more than once, again. Seems an error in my PHP/header logic and not related to this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Apache's `mod_rewrite` the page is in effect loaded twice. As an example, use the following code on your index page:

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if (!isset($_SESSION['id']))
  {
    $_SESSION['id'] = 1;
  }

  else
  {
    $_SESSION['id'] += 1;
  }

  echo $_SESSION['id'];

?>
```

Without using a redirect the output increments by 1 on each refresh. Now add a .htaccess file with the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

Each refresh increments the page by two. I've tried the same using a single `INSERT` query and the same happens: with `.htaccess`, two rows are inserted; without, one row is inserted.

So, if you're using `mod_rewrite` and it affects `download.php` then I believe this is the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this server is an IIS server without any URL rewrite support.

Comment: Ah, you said you *used* to use Apache. Sorry for not reading it correctly.

Comment: Although, saying that, have you tried copying the `$_SESSION` incremental code example I have above (as a stand alone file to keep it simple)? It could be that something else about your server setup is making the page load twice. If it is incrementing by two or more each time then you know the problem isn't your PHP code.

Comment: Testing your PHP code with the incremental variable, every time I hit that page the value increases by 1. In 150 hits, the variable increments by the appropriate value of 1. So after this testing, would that point towards that download.php script being executed twice by incorrect PHP code logic?

Answer (score 1):

Tip: Remove the `?>` from the end of ALL your PHP files. Occasionaly you end up getting an invisible space or newline after it, and when outputting a binary format like PDF it becomes a part of the PDF and makes it corrupt. (Hence browser/PDF reader hang.)

Comment: I'm guessing, but your double-get issue may be related to this order of events: 1) You click the link, which opens up a new browser window which starts loading from your script. 2) The browser gets the headers and understands that the file should be read using a PDF reader. 3) The browser closes the connection, opens a PDF reader with the url as input. 4) The PDF reader runs the script and downloads the file again.

Comment: The PDF file does not hang any longer, after I fixed another error in my script. However, to test the validity of your answer I removed the `?>` from all files. This results in some PHP files not being loaded properly (500 internal) and the double file hit as in the original question.

Comment: Regarding the `?>`, itis very strange, as long as you are just removing the last one in the file it should be fine. Read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php