# PHP PDF download script is executing twice

Tags: php, sql-server, pdf, download

I have a web application using PHP and PDO with SQLSRV prepared statements to display links to files for users to download. The back-end PHP script 'download.php' checks various items before serving the PDF to the user to download. The download.php file then should update a few SQL tables, and serve the PDF file to the user.

Please read my
[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280032/php-pdo-and-sqlsrv-executes-multiple-times-on-one-insert-statement)
 and the troubleshooting completed there, if you need more information.

After troubleshooting, the error I thought was occurring (and thus the previous question I had asked) was incorrect. My download script is getting executed more than once for every file download.

I have searched the server logs and while debugging with Firebug, I can see my download.php script making multiple GET requests to the server. Sometimes the script completes only once as expected. Other times the script executes three to four request for the one click of the download link.

Now that I more fully understand what error is occurring, I need a bit of help fixing it.
I need to prevent the script from running multiple times, and thus updating the SQL table with records that are within a few milliseconds of each other.

The view page checks the SQL database for files the current user is allowed access to, and displays a list of links:

```
<a href='download.php?f={$item['name']}&t={$type}' target='_blank'>{$item['name']}</a>
```

Because the values are needed for the download.php script to work, I cannot change the request to a $_POST instead of $_GET.

What I have tried:

- Checking/setting a session variable for 'downloading' state, before the `getfile()` which unsets right before the `exit(0)`
- Putting the SQL statements in a separate PHP file and require'ing that
- Adding a `sleep(1)` after the `getfile()`
- Commenting out the header/PDF information

The first three measures did not work to prevent the double/triple execution of the PHP download script. However, the last measure DOES prevent the double/triple execution of the PHP script, but of course the PDF is never delivered to the client browser!

**Question**: How can I ensure that only ONE insert/update PER DOWNLOAD is inserted into the database, or at the least, how can I prevent the PHP script from being executed multiple times?

**UPDATE**

Screenshot of issue in firebug:

One request:
[image: one]

Two requests:
[image: two]

**download.php script**

```
<?php
session_start();

require("cgi-bin/auth.php");
// Don't timeout when downloading large files
@ignore_user_abort(1);  
@set_time_limit(0);  

//error_reporting(E_ALL); 
//ini_set('display_errors',1);

function getfile() {
    if (!isset($_GET['f']) || !isset($_GET['t'])) {
        echo "Nothing to do!";
        exit(0);
    }

    require('cgi-bin/connect_db_pdf.php');

    //Update variables
    $vuname = strtolower(trim($_SESSION['uname']));
    $file = trim(basename($_GET['f'])); //Filename we're looking for
    $type = trim($_GET['t']);//Filetype

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]{1,60}$/', $file) || !preg_match('/^av|ds|cr|dp$/', $type)) {
        header('Location: error.php');
        exit(0);
    }

    try {
        $sQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM pdf_info WHERE PDF_name=:sfile AND type=:stype";
        $statm = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
        $statm->execute(array(':sfile'=>$file,':stype'=>$type));
        $result = $statm->fetchAll();
        $count = count($result);
        $sQuery = null;
        $statm = null;

        if ($count == 1 ){ //File was found in the database so let them download it. Update the time as well
            $result = $result[0];

            $sQuery = "INSERT INTO access (PDF_name,PDF_type,PDF_time,PDF_access) VALUES (:ac_file, :ac_type, GetDate(), :ac_vuname); UPDATE pdf_info SET last_view=GetDate(),viewed_uname=:vuname WHERE PDF_name=:file AND PDF_type=:type";

            $statm = $conn->prepare($sQuery);
            $statm->execute(array( ':ac_vuname'=>$vuname, ':ac_file'=>$file, ':ac_type'=>$type,':vuname'=>$vuname, ':file'=>$file, ':type'=>$type));
            $count = $statm->rowCount();
            $sQuery = null;
            $statm = null;


            //$result is the first element from  the SELECT query outside the 'if' scope.
            $file_loc = $result['floc'];
            $file_name = $result['PDF_name'];


            // Commenting from this line to right after the exit(0) updates the database only ONCE, but then the PDF file is never sent to the browser!
            header("Content-Type: application/pdf"); 
            header("Pragma: no-cache");  
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache");  
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_loc));  
            header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
            header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename={$file_name}");  
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($file_loc);
            exit(0);


            } else { //We did not find a file in the database. Redirect the user to the view page.
                header("Location: view.php");
                exit(0);
            }

            }   catch(PDOException $err) {//PDO SQL error. 
            //echo $err;
            header('Location: error.php');
            exit(0);
         }

}

getfile();


?>
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you don't know *what* exactly is causing the multiple downloads, correct? I think it's worth continuing to dig for that instead of trying to patch up the symptom. (Although I have no clue what could be triggering this...)

Comment: @pekka That is correct; I do not know what is causing the multiple executions, I just know they ARE happening. As well, the file itself is not downloaded multiple times that I can tell. The view link only ever opens one window, and one file is downloaded per click.

Comment: Hmm. If Firebug shows multiple "hits" firing, there must be a reason for them. Where exactly do those hits occur? What do they look like? Are you using any JavaScript on your page? Is the download link referenced anywhere else on the page?

Comment: @Pekka: I'm not sure what do you mean, 'where do those hits occur?' Can you clarify?

Comment: what exactly is Firebug saying about the multiple requests? Can you show a screen shot?

Comment: Updated with screenshots @pekka.

Comment: Hmm. And these two entries pop up when you click the download link? Or are they there already when you load the page?

Comment: @Pekka: The entries in firebug show up after clicking the link and the navigation goes to the download.php page. They are reflected in the new window, but not the 'view.php' window. I also noted the headers; if there is more than one request only the first one gives a Referrer. The subsequent calls do not have a referrer in the headers.

Comment: Really weird. What does `cgi-bin/auth.php` do? Does it contain any further header redirects? The only thing I can see that could be causing this is a `header("Location:")` with an empty location (redirecting back to itself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to make sure that a link only creates an event once, then you need to implement a token system, where when a hyperlink (or a form post target) is generated, a use once token is generated and stored (in the session or wherever), and then is checked in the calling script.

So your hyperlink may look like this:

```
<a href='download.php?token={some-token}&f={$item['name']}&t={$type}' target='_blank'>{$item['name']}</a>
```

On the php side this is a really simplified idea of what you might do:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_REQUEST['token']) die(); // or fail better
if (!isset($_SESSION['oneTimeTokens'][$_REQUEST['token']) die(); // or fail better
if ($_SESSION['oneTimeTokens'][$_REQUEST['token']=='used') die(); // or fail better
$_SESSION['oneTimeTokens'][$_REQUEST['token']='used';
// we're good from this point
```

This would solve the effects of your problem, though not the double running itself. However since you want to make sure a link is firing an event only once NO MATTER WHAT, you probably implement this in some form or another as it's the only way to guarantee that any link generated has a one real use life that I can think of.

When generating the link you would do something like this in your code:

```
<?php
$tokenID = {random id generation here};
$_SESSION['oneTimeTokens'][$tokenID] = 'not used';
```

I'd also somewhere put a cleanup routine to remove all used tokens. Also, it's not a bad idea to expire tokens beyond a certain age, but I think this explains it.

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, you are stating to create an individual token on the 'view.php' page that is inserted into the listing of the download links? Then in the PHP script check that token and continue/fail as necessary. That would prevent a link from being valid at another session, but I do not see how it would prevent a double execution of the script by itself. (The question posed is based on the user clicking the download link only once). It is the script that is being executed twice or more.

Comment: I'm guessing something is firing the same request multiple times. If you added a token to the request link, then even if the link were called multiple times, each time the link was called the same token would be passed. However, proper use of tokens, especially when paired with a database transaction, can prevent the script from completing multiple times. You aren't preventing multiple executions of the script. You're just preventing it from running to completion other than the first call.

Comment: Thanks for the reply clarifying your answer. I too have thought of a way to prevent multiple database entries, but not yet the multiple executions. I wrapped the insert/update statement in an if statement that checks for the existence of the referrer, and if present it'll execute the SQL. If not and the last request was within 1 second, it'll skip over the insert/update. Temporary fix until properly fixed. I'm going to accept your answer as I'll look to implement the token and DB method for checks versus what I have currently. Thanks.